# Is there a way to extract the opposite team name from the match column in Power BI using DAX formula?

Tags: powerbi, dax

[This my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlM8w.png)

In match column the entry is Namibia Vs Sri Lanka, and in teaminnings column, there is team name of the player. i want to remove the own team name from match column and just exist the opposite team name, the result is "Vs Opposite Team name"

i try for custom column but i don't get expected result.

Comment: Hi! According to your screenshot it’s PowerQuery and not DAX. Here you can find an overview of Text functions for PowerQuery. You should be able to extract and combine the text subsections to your desire: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new custom column with this below code-

```
"vs " & Replacer.ReplaceText(Replacer.ReplaceText([match]," vs ",""),[teaminnings],"")
```

[image]

---

**OR** add a **Measure** as below-

```
Measure = "vs " & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MIN('Table'[match])," vs ",""),MIN('Table'[teaminnings]),"")
```

---

**Or** add a **Column** as below-

```
Column = "vs " & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE('Table'[match]," vs ",""),'Table'[teaminnings],"")
```

Sample output-

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much vai. it's so helpful.

Comment: @HimelDas nice to see it helped. You can also put an up vote :)